# Como parsear um Json com 2 colunas em Objective-C?

Tags: php, json, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Em um Get usando PHP estou fazendo a requisição de 2 colunas deste modo:

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
//Converte para UTF8 os resultados da query
mysql_set_charset('UTF8');
//Retorna resultado query idRegistro e updateatRegistro
$sql = "SELECT idRegistro,updateatRegistro FROM jump";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro: ".mysql_error());
// Crinha variável linha do tipo array
$linha = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))
    {  
        $linha [] = $r;
    }
 echo json_encode($linha);
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

E estou tentando pegar os valores. Porém percebi que no responseData, estou recebendo uma resposta com 2 camadas de arrays e 1 dicionário:

deste modo:

```
1º Array |2º Array| Dicionario 
    [0] =    [0]    = idRegistro: 1;
             [1]    = updateAt: 2015/02/18 19:55:42;
```

QUando tento extrair os dados da primeira camada do array, o retorno deveria ser outro array, porém está sendo reconhecido como um dicionario. Acredito que seja devido a codificação do Json.

Acredito que devo fazer a query destas colunas de um outro modo. Alguém poderia sugerir uma melhor maneira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de alguns testes, notei que o Xcode reconhece o segundo array como um dicionário, então enviei a mensagem `...valueForKey:@"idRegitro"];` e ele me retornou o valor corretamente.

Porém fiquei estarrecido, pois parece ser um erro de reconhecimento de tipo, provávelmente gerado pelo formato do encode/decode json, gerado no servidor e recebido pela API do Json nativa no Xcode.